# Why did my printer center my book's subtitle although I want it offset to the right?

Tags: formatting, titles

My printer sent to me for my approval the title centered, the subtitle much more than double spaced ( as I had submitted) below it, and also centered. I asked why is my subtitle not offset to the right as I submitted. She replied, "The offset subtitle made it appear as a formatting error. If everything else is centered on the page, the subtitle should be as well. In order for it not to appear to be a formatting error, I recommend: main title, left justified; subtitle, centered; author name, right justified. That looks horrible. Is there a way to get around the printer's objection? Perhaps a macro?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Printer just print page according to instruction which it receive. Eventually it can add printer border (a small white border around page), if you set printer to do so. For more, we need to see a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem

Comment: @Zarko, I have a feeling that in this case the printer is a person not a thing.

Comment: LaTeX can do anything against the tastes of a printer/editor/publisher, so this is off-topic here.  What you can do depend on of who has the final say.  If your work is for some journal, I am afraid that your options are (a) fully accept the proposed format or (b)  search another journal to publish your work.

Comment: Yes, "printer' in this case is a person. Based on the ambiguity of the above-cited statement from her, I assumed she was stating her opinion, not reciting a formatting necessity. I was right. She responded with the title page as I had submitted and without comment. My thanks to the above respondents.